# How to interpreting linear regression model produced from gradient descent after normalization

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

If I normalize training data then apply the gradient descent algorithm which outputs hypothesis h(x1,...,xn), I understand that I need to also apply the same corresponding transformations to the x1,...,xn of any new test data before plugging into h if we'd like to get predictions for this test data. My question is - what is the interpretation/use of this predicted value, given that the inputs have been transformed and the output prediction we are interested would likely be one computed from non-transformed inputs? (E.g. If the output we are predicting using the model is house pricing, a prediction of y=7 is of no practical use; it seems to me that an actual prediction of housing price, like y=750k, would be more valuable.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether, before fitting the regression model, you normalized both your independent (x) and dependent (y) variables, or only the independent ones. In the first case (both x and y transformed), the predictions you'd get out of your regression model would be in the transformed domain, so you'd have to reverse the transformation to get interpretable results (e.g. if you multiplied your training y-data by a certain constant, you have to divide the predictions by that same constant). In the second case (only x transformed) the predictions you get are already on the same scale as the original data, so they can be interpreted directly.

(Note that I'm assuming here that, when generating predictions, you make sure to first transform your x-data the same way that you did when fitting the model to the training data (as you mention in the beginning of your question).)